# how to change div background image in mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, onmouseover

I have 7 thumbnail image menus.when user points`(mouseover)` to a particular thumbnail, I want to change the background-image of `<div>` to the regarding image of that thumbnail.

**thumbnail images menu are in a diff div**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('div.someclass').hover(function(){
       $(this).addClass('hover_class');
    }, function(){
       $(this).addClass('mouseout_class');
    }
  );
});
```

Where you have specified the `hover_class` and `mouseout_class` in your style sheet with corresponding  images eg

```
<style type="text/css">
 .hover_class {
    background-image: url(url 1);
 }

 .mouseout_class{
    background-image: url(url 2);
 }
</style>
```

Comment: but `url 1` is not fixed, as I said I have 7 thumbnails so how I can display seven diff images?

Answer (score 7):

Whats wrong with pure css?

```
div.thumbnail:hover {
 background-image: url(image/in/question);
}
```

Simply change the div.thumbnail to reflect your div and class or id name (in case of id replace `.`with `#`)

Comment: Make sure to use a CSS Sprite to avoid a flicker in the rollover caused by the new image loading. Here is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932566/how-do-css-sprites-work

Comment: @Sarfraz - That may not be an issue, it's not for any of my current projects, *hopefully* that's the case everywhere soon.

Comment: @Nick Craver: That's true but IE6 is still around albeit with lesser number :(

Comment: I'm going to use this regardless. Users of IE6 just won't get to experience the full effect of my site. It's their loss. If we continue catering to these users, they may never see the need to upgrade. (I know a lot of users are in a corporate environment, so it's really up to the IT guys... but still)

Answer (score 0):

do

```
$('#thumbnailimg').hover(function(){
    $('#changeme').css('background-image', $(this).children('img').attr('src'));
}, function(){
    $('#changeme').css('background-image', '');
});
```