# CSS: normal and hover background image in a single image file

Tags: css

Good day, I have a DIV of fixed width and height on my HTML page. In normal state it should show image A on the background and in hover state it should show image B. I know how to do it using CSS and two image files A and B. Somewhere I saw those two images (A and B) put into a single image file and then they somehow wrote CSS so that in normal state the DIV showed upper half of the image on the background and in a hover state it showed the bottom half of the image. Could you please advise CSS code to achieve this? The DIV has no position set but it is a child of a DIV with relative position. Thank you in advance.

Vojtech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called CSS spriting and is an awesome technique that everyone should use.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932566/how-do-css-sprites-work) for a good overview. What it comes down to is having a DOM element with a defined height and width and using a background image that is larger than that area. Then you can selectively show only portions of that background image using `background-position`