# How to extract icon from picture and display it in page? (by javascript or jquery or css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following picture:

[image]

**How to I can extract one icon from this picture and display it in page? (by java script or jquery or css)**

Comment: use `background-position : 0px 20px`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do CSS sprites work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932566/how-do-css-sprites-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to get star grey color

```
<style>div {
height: 28px;
width: 30px;
background: url(./FsZ0N.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -152px;
}</style>
<div></div>
```

to get other icone you need  to decrees -152px more

Comment: Note, that for images with different size, you also need to change width and height.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about sprites. Example:

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url(your/path/to/image.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 100px;
}
```

Little more to read: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ or here on SO [How do CSS sprites work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932566/how-do-css-sprites-work)